# Create a Combined Excel Column Given Month and Year

Tags: excel

If I've been given a year (ex 1980) and a month (January) - how could I create a new column in excel to show a combined date - such as Jan-80?

The date function doesn't work since it requires a day and one has not been provided for this example.

Tried the date function and it did not work given requirement for a day value.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
=TEXT(DATE(A1, MONTH(DATEVALUE(B1 & " 1")), 1), "mmm-yy")
```

The [DATE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349#:%7E:text=The%20DATE%20function%20returns%20the,that%20represents%20a%20particular%20date.&text=The%20DATE%20function%20syntax%20has,include%20one%20to%20four%20digits.) function puts together the year, month number, and a set day (1). Then, the [TEXT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) function changes the date format to "mmm-yy". Here, "mmm" means the short month name, and "yy" means the two-number year.

[image]

Comment: Or `=TEXT(DATEVALUE(B1&" 1, " &A1),"mmm-yy")`, or `=TEXT(--(B1&" 1, " &A1),"mmm-yy")`

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of how Excel casts strings as dates, based on your local/time settings. Assuming you have the month in cell `A1` and the year in cell `B1`:

```
=0+("1-"&A1&"-"&B1)
```

**Note**: later I found out that the dash delimiter (`-`), at least for my local time/settings) is not really needed and some parenthesis, as well as the day one can be a number:

```
=0+1&A1:A2&B1:B2
```

The output is a date type (number), then you can format it in a date format of your preference or use the `TEXT` function:

```
=TEXT(0+("1-"&A1&"-"&B1),"mmm-yy")
```

Here is the output:
[image: output1]

where `29221` is the numeric representation of the date: `1-Jan-1980`. As you can see it works in array form, so you can convert a range using a similar approach. The following also works: `0+TEXTJOIN("-",,"1",A1,B1)` but not for a range, you need to drag it down.

Here is the output after applying `TEXT` function:
[image: output2]